# Does the session die if a user lands on a page without session_start()?

Tags: php

I've got a site with several hundred pages.  Most of the pages do not have session_start() at the top.  I do have it on the index.php page, where I need some info from a session variable.  But, if a user navigates away to a page without session_start(), then goes back to the index.php page, the session is no longer active.  Is this correct?  Do I need it on EVERY page to keep it active?

Comment: No. As long as the session cookie stays "live" in the browser, and the server doesn't nuke the corresponding session file, then the session is "live". It might be unused, but it won't get trashed just because you happened to hit a page that doesn't actually use it. If it stays unused long enough, then it WILL get cleaned up and destroyed.

Comment: I think I {{MIGHT}} have figured out my issue.  I was bouncing from www.domain.com to domain.com.  I'm guessing this kills the session as it is viewed as a new URL.  Does this sound like it could be my issue?  When changing everything to www.domain.com it seems to work as I hoped.

Answer (score 3):

The session `activity` is determined by the last time the session data was accessed by your code (literally - the last time you invoked `session_start()`).

If the time passed since last access is more than `session.gc_maxlifetime` then it's collected by garbage collector (with some probability).

So - having a page without `session_start()` wouldn't explicitly "terminate" it, but not accessing session data for some time - would.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It all works based on a cookie stored in the browser. The browser sends the cookie and PHP uses that to load the session data. If the cookie is sent, but the session is not started, using `session_start`, the data is still there. (Usually stored in `/tmp` somewhere.)